# Two unordered list side by side opposite to each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to put two UnorderedList (Contents are generated dynamically) opposite to each other (one on the left hand side of screen and one on the right hand side) but on the same line but the second list is always offset by a vertical margin and is floating below the first list (Opposite end of screen but below first list)

```
  <div data-role="content" id="home"> 
        <h4 style="float: left; width: 50%;">Below Employees have just checked in the Premises</h4>
        <h4 style="float: right; width: 50%; text-align: right;">Employee below has just now taken off his/her safety helmet</h4> 
        <ul style="width:200px;float:left;clear:both;display: inline-block;padding:5px" data-role="listview" id="listView1" data-inset="true"></ul> 
        <ul style="width:200px;float:right;clear:both;display: inline-block;padding:5px" data-role="listview" id="listView2" data-inset="true"></ul>
  </div>
```

I tried all CSS styles but I simply cannot get the second list to lie side by side the first list (but on the opposite end of screen)

Contents of LIST are generated dynamically this way (Though I feel that is not going to be important for the problem as stated above).

```
var $li = $("<li>").attr("data-filtertext",msg.userID).appendTo("#listView1");
        $("<a>").attr("href","#")
                .attr("id",msg.userID)
                .text(msg.userID)
                .appendTo($li)
                .css("background", "#F68D78");
        $("#listView1").listview('refresh')
```

***SOLUTION WHICH WORKS (thanks to David for the solution)***
Removed **clear:both** and problem is solved

Comment: are you using bootstrap or not?

Comment: First move your styles to a CSS stylesheet file. This will make your life a lot easier.

Comment: `clear: both` would seem to be the problem; the `clear` rule places the element to which that rule is applied clear of the floated elements. See the MDN documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/clear

Comment: Thanks a lot David, I have been struggling for last two hours. Solved. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you are looking for, removing `clear:both` from the ul and putting `clear:both;` to a following element:

```html
<div data-role="content" id="home"> 
  <h4 style="float: left; width: 50%;">Below Employees have just checked in the Premises</h4>
  <h4 style="float: right; width: 50%; text-align: right;">Employee below has just now taken off his/her safety helmet</h4> 
  <br style="clear:both;">
  <ul style="width:200px;float:left;display: inline-block;padding:5px" data-role="listview" id="listView1" data-inset="true">List 1</ul> 
  <ul style="width:200px;float:right;display: inline-block;padding:5px" data-role="listview" id="listView2" data-inset="true">List 2</ul>
  <br style="clear:both;">
</div>
```

p.s. please keep your styles outside the HTML and use CSS files. Keep the code clearer

Answer (score 0):

What `clear:both` will help to clear after the floats. So in case you have issues with this - use also `clear:both`.

Try this one:

```
<div data-role="content" id="home"> 
    <h4 style="float: right; width: 50%; text-align: right;">Employee below has just now taken off his/her safety helmet</h4> 
    <h4 style="float: left; width: 50%;">Below Employees have just checked in the Premises</h4>
    <ul style="width:200px;float:right;clear:both;display: inline-block;padding:5px" data-role="listview" id="listView2" data-inset="true"></ul>
    <ul style="width:200px;float:left;clear:both;display: inline-block;padding:5px" data-role="listview" id="listView1" data-inset="true"></ul>
</div>
```